# How to find and delete many numbers in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a 300 page research paper and I have to delete probably close to 1000 items, for example:

> action seeking to enjoin the defendants from violating the minimum wage requirements and to enforce *1532 the record-keeping and child labor provisions of the Act.

I need to delete the *1532 which normally the easy Ctrl+F *1532 would be the route, but the numbers are all different so I would have to start from the highest one and count down (but the numbers aren't in any simple order because of the nature of the paper). How can I remove all such strings?

Comment: What version of Word do you have?  It'll help with testing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Word 2003.

In order to search and replace all occurrence of " *####" strings in your document, I used the following search parameter with the "Use wildcards" option:

```
 \*<[0-9]*>
```

Note the space in front of the first "**\**"

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming after you remove the *1532 in the example, you want only a single space between "enforce" and "the".

Comment: thank you so much, if it isn't clear law students aren't the most computer programming knowledgable

Comment: No problem.  If the answer worked, an upvote would be great :)  Also, it's part of my job to help people, so this is right up my alley.